# Unity Point-cloud to mesh with texture/color

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, mesh, point-clouds

I have a point-cloud and a rgb texture that fit together from a depth camera. I procedurally created a mesh from a selected part of the point-cloud implementing the quickhull 3D algorithm for mesh creation.

Now, somehow I need to apply the texture that I have to that mesh. Note that there can be multiple selected parts of the point-cloud thus making multiple objects that need the texture. The texture is just a basic 720p file that should be applied to the mesh material.

Basically I have to do this: https://www.andreasjakl.com/capturing-3d-point-cloud-intel-realsense-converting-mesh-meshlab/  but inside Unity. (I'm also using a RealSense camera)

I tried with a decal shader but the result is not precise. The UV map is completely twisted from the creation process, and I'm not sure how to generate a correct one.

[UV and the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWzeq.jpg)

I only have two ideas but don't really know if they'll work/how to do them.

1. Try to create a correct UV and then wrap the texture around somehow
2. Somehow bake colors to vertices and then use vertex colors to create the desired effect.

What other things could I try?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on quite a similar problem. But in my case I just want to create a complete mesh from the point cloud. Not just a quickhull, because I don't want to lose any depth information.

I'm nearly done with the mesh algorithm (just need to do some optimizations). Quite challenging now is to match the RGB camera's texture with the depth camera sensor's point cloud, because they of course have a different viewport.

Intel RealSense provides an interesting whitepaper about this problem and as far as I know the SDK corrects these different perspectives with uv mapping and provides a red/green uv map stream for your shader.

Maybe the short report can help you out. Here's the [link](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/projection-texture-mapping-and-occlusion-with-intel-realsense-depth-cameras). I'm also very interested in what you are doing. Please keep us up to date.

Regards

Comment: If you know the offset from the depth camera to the color camera you can project textures from the color cameras position instead from the depth camera.